# Overloading operators on types I don't own

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

Is it possible in C# to override operators on types I don't have control of? E.g. I tried to override add operator for arrays:

```
public static double[] operator +(double[] a, double[] b)
{
...
}
```

but it complains that `At least one parameter should be <enclosing type>`. In C++ one would just create a function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since double[] is a built in type and you can't add operators to it, you could create a wrapper class to do this:

E.g (from wudzik's link):

```
public class Foo
{
    double[] x;

    // Legal
    public static double[] operator+(double[] x, Foo y);
```